# Why won't this image change on mouse over using this.src?

Tags: html, css, image, html-table, this

I'm stumped. I have no idea why this won't change the image source on mouse over ... I created a separate test page and did this no problem, but it won't work with my actual div page ...

**HTML**

```
<div id="nav">
    <div id="nav_left">
        <table class="nav_left">
            <tr><td>
                <img src="arrowdown.png" onmouseover="this.src='arrowdownhover.png'" onmouseout="this.src='arrowdown.png'"/>
            </td></tr>
        </table>
```

**CSS**

```
#nav {
    background-color: #272729;
    width: 99%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 55px;
}

#nav_left {
    width: 30%;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 55px;
}
table.nav_left {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
    height: 55px;
    width: 10%;
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 1em;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually had to add:

```
img {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1000;
}
```

to get this to work.

I had thought that Mahesh was right, but as soon as I removed the `<td>` tags from the img, it worked perfectly fine at the size it was at.

I'm guessing the img was just behind the `<td>` cell. The img css was something I forgot to post, I had not specified a position.

Thanks for the help everyone!

Answer (score 1):

If your image is not loaded or size of image is too small to recognize a mouseover event, it will fire the mouseout event as well.

your code looks fine just add some height and width to image.

[Feedle](https://jsfiddle.net/rqbe4mjn/1/) shows working example of the same

```
<img style="height:100px; width:100px;" src="arrowdown.png" onmouseover="this.src='arrowdownhover.png';" onmouseout="this.src='arrowdown.png';"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Throw in semi colons before you end the script as shown below and it should work.

`<img src="arrowdown.png" onmouseover="this.src='arrowdownhover.png';" onmouseout="this.src='arrowdown.png';"/>`

Comment: No luck unfortunately. I thought that might be it as well.